# Divisors ending with digits 0-9 each

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, optimization, number-theory

What is the smallest positive integer, which has - for each of the digit 0-9 - a divisor ending with this digit?

Comment: `LCM(1, 2, ..., 9, 10) = 2520` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's

> $270$, which has divisors $1, 2, 3, 54, 5, 6, 27, 18, 9, 10$.

Note that

> the number must be a multiple of $10$

and then just

> try every multiple of $10$ until it hits.

Comment: Because 10 is coprime with with any number ending in 9 then you only need to check multiples of 90,190,290,... which significantly reduces the search space.